# Windows Mobile unread message count wrong

Tags: windows-mobile, inbox, messaging

I have a WinMo 6.1 PPC phone, and it keeps saying that I have one unread sms/mms message, but i have looked through ALL my folders, and there are no unread messages.

After googling around, I found some little app, FixUnreadCount.exe, that you just copy to your phone, and run, and it is supposed to reset the counts. I tried that, but it did not fix it.

Anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wound up being fixed in two parts. First, I downloaded [Inbox Extender](http://blogs.msdn.com/dennisq/archive/2006/08/29/730874.aspx) which adds **Mark all Read** and **Delete All** to the pocket Outlook menu. Then using Mark all Read got rid of the unread SMS (but not the MMS).

Then, next time someone else sent me an MMS message, that seemed to make the MMS unread count reset properly.

Ghosts in the machine!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a common and known problem in Windows Mobile (6, 6.1). I haven't come across any solution other than using this freeware tool.